How to use Hahn Banach in order to prove that $C_0(\mathbf{R})\otimes C_0(\mathbf{R})$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbf{R}^2)$?
Let $\mathfrak{X}:=\{u\otimes v:\;u,v\in C_0(\mathbf{R})\}$, where $u\otimes v$ is given by $$(u\otimes v)(x,y)=u(x)v(y),\;\forall x,y\in\mathbf{R}.$$Prove that the linear subspace generated by $\mathfrak{X}$, denoted $\mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{X})=:C_0(\mathbf{R})\otimes C_0(\mathbf{R})$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbf{R}^2)$ with respect to $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\infty}$, where $C_0(\mathbf{R})$ is the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity.
$\textbf{Observation:}$ I have found the following corollary of Hahn-Banach:
Let $(E, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space and $F$ a subspace of $E$. Then $\overline{F} = E$ if and only if the only continuous linear form on $E$ that vanishes on $F$ is the zero linear form, i.e.,
$$
\forall f \in E^*, \quad f(x) = 0 \ \text{for all} \ x \in F \quad \Longrightarrow \quad f = 0.
$$
$\textbf{What I've tried:}$ Choose  $f\in C_0({\bf R}^2)^*$ with $f_{\vert\mathfrak{X}}\equiv 0$. We know that there is a unique Radon measure $\nu$ such that $fu=\int u d\nu,\;\forall u\in C_0(\mathbf{R})$. I think I should reach the point where $\nu$ vanishes on a generating set for the borelians (where it is defined), in order to conclude. But I cannot see how to reach this.

Please add to the post what you have tried so far.

@MartinBrandenburg i added the little information I knew to make use of.

Related self-deleted solution by the same author, using Stone-Weierstrass.

Thank you, @AnneBauval for mentioning the post that was not suited for this site, as you have informed me. Now, as Weierstrass was not receiving any feedback here, i try Hahn-Banach, is there anything wrong with this post too? Please, let me know.

What I "informed you" of, about your previous post, is only that it was lacking some focus, about what you were doubting at.

Do you need to use the Hahn-Banach theorem or are you willing to use other methods? This can be solved by an argument involving Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

@DeanMiller S-W theorem is good too.

@Jack In that case, you may want to change the title as it gives the appearance that you only want to solve the problem using a Hahn-Banach theorem.

To finish your proof using Hahn-Banach, consider a rectangle $I_1\times I_2\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ where $I_1,I_2$ are bounded intervals in $\Bbb R$. It suffices to show that $\nu(I_1\times I_2)=0$. The point is that we can approximate the indicator function of $I_1\times I_2$ by functions in $\frak X$. There are sequences $\varphi^n_1,\varphi^n_2$ such that all functions have support contained in the same compact set, are uniformly bounded and $\varphi^n_i\to\chi_{I_i}$ as $i\to\infty$ for $i=1,2$ (you can write down such a sequence very explicitly). Then by the dominated convergence theorem we have $$
\nu(I_1\times I_2)=\int\chi_{I_1}(x)\chi_{I_2}(y)d\nu(x,y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\varphi_1^n\otimes\varphi_2^nd\nu=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\varphi_1^n\otimes\varphi_2^n)=0.
$$

Thank you! Is there a general form for the approximatimg functions? I'd say something like $\varphi^n=\min (1,n\cdot \text{dist} (x, I^c) $ for$I$ closed. Or if you have a more explicit way for arriving at a specific form, please. @leoli1 ps: is this the complete argument? Or is there anything that should be treated with care?

Yes, I was thinking of something like that. In this case this is definitely a complete argument (after writing out the details e.g. verifying the hypothesis of dominated convergence and why $\nu(I_1\times I_2)=0$ suffices etc.), there is a small problem when you want to generalize this to locally compact Hausdorff spaces (the SW solution immediately applies to that case as well), the reason is that I don't see if there still exists a \textit{sequence} (rather than net for which DCT might be a problem) of such $\varphi$. But you can fix that using to the the regularity of $\nu$ instead of DCT.

where did you use the fact that the functions are continuous and vanishing at infinity? (sure, compactly supported functions are also of this kind) Was this much of an restriction or could we have another more general class of functions?

We use this to get the existence of $\nu$ (because $C_0(\Bbb R^2)=C(X)$). I am not sure about other spaces. For example if we replace $C_0$ by $C_b$ (continuous bounded functions), the SW solution no longer works because SW fails in this case. I wouldn't be surprised if the result was actually wrong in this case (think of functions in $C_b(\Bbb R^2)$ that are ``very wild'' on the diagonal)

Recall the following formulation of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $A$ be a subalgebra of $C(X)$. If $A$ separates the points, vanishes nowhere and is self-adjoint then $A$ is dense in $C(X)$.

An extension to the locally compact Hausdorff case is provided below.

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $A$ be a subalgebra of $C_{0}(X)$. If $A$ separates the points, vanishes nowhere and is self-adjoint then $A$ is dense in $C_{0}(X)$.

This can be obtained from the first formulation of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem for compact Hausdorff spaces by applying the first formulation to the one-point compactification of $X$.
As a result, all you have to do is show that $\mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{X})$ satisfies the hypothesis of the second formulation of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. Checking all of these conditions involves essentially routine tasks. You will most likely need that for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is some $u\in C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $u(x) = 1$. The existence of such functions can follow from one of two methods. You can either obtain such functions from Urysohn's lemma or can directly construct such functions using a more explicit method.
Note that essentially the same proof shows that $C_{0}(X) \otimes C_{0}(Y)$ is dense in $C_{0}(X\times Y)$ for any locally compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ and $Y$.
